# After imputation, how to round to nearest level of a factor

Tags: r

I have imputed missing values in the following data frame in column `q1. q1` is a factor with the levels `0,20,40,60,80,100`. I need to round the column `q1` to nearest level of factors, number `49 and 91` need to be rounded. Does anyone have a solution for this problem?, thanks in advance!

```
id <- rep(c(300,450), each=6)
> visit <- rep(1:6,2)
> trt <- rep(c(0,"A",0,"B",0,"C"),2)
> q1 <- c(0,100,0,89,0, 60,0,85,0,40,0, 20)
> df <- data.frame(id,visit,trt,q1)
> df
    id visit trt  q1
1  300     1   0   0
2  300     2   A 100
3  300     3   0   0
4  300     4   B  49
5  300     5   0   0
6  300     6   C  60
7  450     1   0   0
8  450     2   A  91
9  450     3   0   0
10 450     4   B  40
11 450     5   0   0
12 450     6   C  20
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use `plyr`'s `round_any` function here which would round to nearest multiple of 20 in this case.

```
plyr::round_any(df$q1, 20)
#[1]   0 100   0  80   0  60   0  80   0  40   0  20
```

Comment: Very elegant solution, but df$q1 are to be factors, correct?

Comment: Yes q1 will be converted to a factor after rounding

Comment: @Pleasedon'tlaughatme They are not factors in the data which OP shared, if needed they can be converted to factors later.

Comment: @RonakShah, apologies for the confusion. Yes, clearly the data shared by the OP is numeric but the question stated that they should be factors.